# Suddenly getting Errors : Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'Queries per day'

Tags: google-analytics, limit, default, quota

We suddenly started getting errors from Google Analytics while fetching data for transactions..

> Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'Queries per day' of service 'analytics.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:251xxxxxxx09'. [403]

We had this issue before and it got resolved next day.. but it gets annoying for users.

Is anyone else facing this issue?